# How to upload Flipping book material to Tridion CMS?

Tags: content-manager

We need to upload the Flipping book material to the Tridion CMS. These materials are PDF files that have been converted to digital html5 flipbook via flippingbook tool. IS it possible to upload these flipping book to the Tridion CMS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to serve the flipping books as binary files from your own servers, then it should simply be a question of creating a suitable multimedia type (you can find these under the Administration menu of the Tridion Explorer). Then you can create a multimedia schema that accepts this type, and begin creating multimedia components and uploading your flipping books into them.

I don't know much about flipping books, but from their web site it looks rather as though they are hosted "as a service" and that what you put into your page is simply a reference. In this case, you could consider making a schema for a very simple configuration component that allows you to store the reference for use in your templates.

This kind of external content also has direct support in Tridion: Setting up an  [External Content Library](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-948FBBE8-6127-4943-981F-BB2FDF87C2C6) will give you all the benefits of the simpler approach, but will also allow for more ease of use for your web editing team.